# c# Linq query with Tuple List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, tuples

I have 2 database tables.

In Table1 `Calculate` I have 1 row which is mapped via an `Id` to multiple rows in table2 `CalculdateData`.

Now I need to load the data from table1 `Calculate` with all relevant Details from Table2 `CalculdateData`.

**How would i have the Details into a `Tuple-List.?`**

So basically for `CalculateData` I have 4 columns per row which I Need to put into a Tuple. Meaning if I would have for example 4 rows i need to create 4 Tuples in a List.

```
IEnumerable<Storage> context = new MyEntities();

var Result = (from a in context.calculate
             join b in context.CalculateData on a.Id equals b.CalcId into c
             where a.SpecialID == 2023 && a.VersionId == 1
             orderby a.InternalOrderNr ascending
             select new Storage
             {
                myField1 = a.Field1;
                myField2 = a.Field2;
                myField3 = a.Field3;
                < MISSING PART AND QUESTION >
             }).ToList();

            return Result;


public class Storage
{
            public int myField1;
            public int myField2;
            public int myField3;
            public List<Tuple<int, int, string, decimal>> myField4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
        var Result = (from a in calculate
                      join b in calculateData on a.Id equals b.CalcId into c
                      where a.SpecialID == 2023 && a.VersionId == 1
                      orderby a.InternalOrderNr ascending
                      select new Storage
                      {
                          myField1 = a.Field1,
                          myField2 = a.Field2,
                          myField3 = a.Field3,
                          myField4 = c.Select(d => new Tuple<int, int, string, decimal>
                                                   (d.Field1, d.Field2, d.Field3, d.Field4))
                                                   .ToList()
                      }).ToList();

        return Result;
```

It also would be good thing to check that this query transforms in single sql request and you not making new sql request on each tuple list creation.

**Edit:** In case you will have problems with custom types in query (as @Toxantron pointed) this selection should work:

```
    var queryResult = (from a in calculate
                              join b in calculateData on a.Id equals b.CalcId into c
                              where a.SpecialID == 2023 && a.VersionId == 1
                              orderby a.InternalOrderNr ascending
                              select new
                              {
                                  a.Field1,
                                  a.Field2,
                                  a.Field3,
                                  myField4 = c.Select(d => new {
                                               d.Field1, d.Field2, d.Field3, d.Field4})


                              }).ToList();
    result = queryResult.Select(r => new Storage
    {
        myField1 = r.Field1,
        myField2 = r.Field2,
        myField3 = r.Field3,
        myField4 = r.myField4.Select(t => new Tuple<int,int,decimal,string>
                                          (t.Field1, t.Field2, t.Field3, t.Field4))
                             .ToList()
    })

    return Result;
```

Comment: I am not sure about latest Entity Framework, but till EF 6.1 it was not possible to use non-default constructors in Linq2Entities.

Comment: @Toxantron that also my concern, I think it still not possible, and we will have to select anonymous type and transform it after selection.

Comment: I think only in memory `Select` only be possible

Comment: @Eldho selection with anonymous type should work on database side. There might be a problems with tuple list selection (could create sub request), I guess it could be solved, but can't suggest 100% solution without testing on real database.

Comment: Hi Guys, great post. It is working with you snippet above. But I have an another tricky task to solve on top of this. Example:
This is the Tuple: public List<Tuple<int, int, string, decimal>> myField4;

The string describes the decimal value. 
1,2,Values from Database column 1, ValueColumn1
1,2,Values from Database column 2, ValueColumn2
1,2,Values from Database column 3, ValueColumn3

Is it clear what I'm trying to say?

Comment: @Maik sorry but it's not clear for me, may be you can explain it in different  way of add it to your question

Comment: As the original answer has been given in this context I have created an extended query under: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875107/c-sharp-linq-query-filling-a-tuple-list

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.This is not tested yet.

```
select new Storage
 {
         myField1 = a.Field1,
         myField2 = a.Field2,
         myField3 = a.Field3,
         myField4 = c.Select(d => new Tuple<int, int, string, decimal>(d.Field1, d.Field2, d.Field3, d.Field4)).ToList()
 }).ToList();
```

This is totally based on this [This tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple)

Comment: No, this is not what I want. The Fields myField1, myField2 and myField3 containing 1 value and the myField4 can contain several values. myField4 is a List (List<Tuple<int, int, string, decimal>> myField4) Check out my Class Storage which I defined.